# Class not found DB2Driver in debezium db2 kafka connect

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, debezium

I am trying to deploy debezium db2 connector using the Kafka connect (debezium immutable docker images).
but when i deploy the db2 connector using kafka REST api, it gives the following error in kafka connect logs.

```
"2021-06-13 14:24:35,225 ERROR  ||  WorkerSourceTask{id=lifestyle-connector-0} Task threw an uncaught and unrecoverable exception. Task is being killed and will not recover until manually restarted   [org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask]           
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/ibm/db2/jcc/DB2Driver
    at io.debezium.connector.db2.Db2Connection.<clinit>(Db2Connection.java:91)
    at io.debezium.connector.db2.Db2ConnectorTask.start(Db2ConnectorTask.java:74)
    at io.debezium.connector.common.BaseSourceTask.start(BaseSourceTask.java:130)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask.execute(WorkerSourceTask.java:232)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.doRun(WorkerTask.java:185)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.run(WorkerTask.java:234)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)                                   
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:471)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:589)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.PluginClassLoader.loadClass(PluginClassLoader.java:104)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
    ... 11 more"
```

I have referred following tutorial
https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/tutorial.html#starting-kafka-connect

Comment: Did you add the DB2 driver to the image's classpath?

Comment: @OneCricketeer I am new to docker, can you please tell me how to do that?

Comment: The issue has nothing to do with Docker. The tutorial you're following is for mysql. Debezium doesn't come with a DB2 JDBC client, which you'd need to download from IBM on your own. And you don't need to use Docker to use Debezium, so start without Docker, for simplicity

Comment: @OneCricketeer I am using the immutable docker images and I am not sure how to add DB2 jar in image classpath

Comment: Will use without docker first

Comment: The install guide can be found here https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/connectors/db2.html#db2-deploying-a-connector

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have logged into the kafka connect using bin bash and copied the db2 dependancies jar from my local to lib folder.
This solved my problem.